# Prove by induction $n^2 + n \geq 42$ when $n \geq 6$ and $n \leq -7$ (induction with two different intervals)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

I am asked the following:

> Prove by induction $n^2 + n \geq 42$ when $n \geq 6$ and $n \leq -7$

The first part of the exercise seems ok:

**Base case**
P(6): $\quad LHS = 36+6=42\geq 42$

**Inductive hypothesis**
$\quad P(k) : k^2 + k \geq 42$

**Inductive step**
$$ (k+1)^2 + (k+1) = k^2 + 2k + 1 + k + 1 = k^2 + k + (2k+2) > k^2 + k \geq 42$$

Now, for the second part:

**Base case**
P(7): $\quad LHS = 49-7=42\geq 42$

**Inductive hypothesis**
$\quad P(k) : k^2 + k \geq 42$

**Inductive step**
$$\quad (k+1)^2 + (k+1) = \cdots$$ (not sure how to go from here)

My intuition says I need to use the fact that I have a negative $n$ and use it to my favor, however, I am not sure how.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You don't mean "$n \ge 6$ **and** $n \le -7$", you mean **or**.

Comment: For the case $n \le -7$, you want to organize the induction in the negative direction, i.e. go from $n$ to $n-1$, not $n+1$.  Or you could just notice that $n^2 + n = (-1-n)^2 + (1-n)$

Comment: @RobertIsrael:  the equation you said to notice appears mistaken.  Perhaps you meant $...+(\color{red}-1-n)$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, that's what I meant, thanks

Answer (score 3):

First part is fine, for the second part to avoid negative number we can use that by $m=-n>0$ such that

$$n^2 + n \geq 42 \;\text{for}\; n\le -7 \iff m^2-m\ge 42 \;\text{for}\; m\ge 7$$

and proceed in a similar way as for the first part.

---

As suggested by Robert Israel in the comments, also note that for $m\ge 7$ by $p=m-1\ge 6$ we have

$$ m^2-m\ge 42 \;\text{for}\; m\ge 7 \iff  p^2+p\ge 42 \;\text{for}\; p\ge 6$$

which was already proved by the first part.

Answer (score 1):

proving $n^2+n\geq42$ for $n\leq-7$

Since $f(n)=n^2+n-42$ is a quadratic, by taking reflection of $f(n)=n^2+n-42$ about y axis that is $f(-n)=n^2-n-42$, prove $n\geq 7$ for $n^2-n\geq 42$

step $1$: for $n=7$

$7^2-7=42$ is true.

step $2$: assume that it is true for $n=k$,

$k^2-k\geq 42$

then  for $n=k+1$

$(k+1)^2-(k+1)=k^2+k > k^2-k\geq 42$, for $n=7$.